# extracting integer from string

Tags: c#, .net

This might be really simple but i have a service that returns a string that has a number preceded with zeros. The count of zeros is not predictable but i need to extract the number out of the value. The length of the value is also not constant. For ex. `00001234, 002345667, 0000000, 011, 00000987` - in all these values, i need to extract the `1234, 2345667, <no value>, 11, 987`. 
i have tried doing the below code but it returns the zeros as well:

```
string.Join( null,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( expr, "[^\\d]" ) );
```

Can anyone help?

***Got my Answer::***

I got it using `stringObj.TrimStart('0')`. But i agree using Int.Parse or Int.TryParse is a better way of handling. Hope this is useful to someone like me!

Comment: So how does `TrimStart` handle values like `-000012`? Or will you always have positive integers?

Comment: yes, it will always be positive integers but I would agree using int.Parse or Int.TryParse is a better option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int ret;

if (int.TryParse("0001234", out ret))
{
    return ret.ToString();
}

throw new Exception("eep");
```

Comment: Cleanest code, TryParse is never as slick, but much higher quality than a straight parse.

Comment: Agree to that. But I believe that OP prefer a cast. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
var numString = "00001234, 002345667, 0000000, 011, 00000987";

// result will contain "1234, 2345667, <no value>, 11, 987"
var result = string.Join(", ", numString.Split().Select(s => 
    {
        var intVal = int.Parse(s);
        return intVal == 0 ? "<no value>" : intVal.ToString();
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast to integer and back to string?

```
int num    = Convert.ToInt32(val);
string val = Convert.ToString(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
string s = "0005";
string output = Convert.ToInt32(s.TrimStart(Convert.ToChar("0")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The power of regular expressions to the rescue!

```
static readonly Regex rx = new Regex( @"[^\d]*((0*)([1-9][0-9]*)?)" ) ;
public static IEnumerable<string> ParseNumbers( string s )
{
  for ( Match matched = rx.Match(s) ; matched.Success ; matched = matched.NextMatch() )
  {
    if ( matched.Groups[1].Length > 0 )
    {
      yield return matched.Groups[3].Value ;
    }
  }
}
```

Passing the string `"00001234, 002345667, 0000000, 011, 00000987"` to `ParseNumbers()` yields the enumeration

- "1234"
- "2345667"
- ""
- "11"
- "987"

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

000000 is 0 not null....

```
int intInteger = -1;
int.tryparse(stringNumber,out intInteger);
```

should give you a clean integer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328655%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to parse the string into an integer.

```
    String s = "00001234, 002345667, 0000000, 011, 00000987";
    string[] nums= s.Split(',');
foreach (string num in nums
{
    Console.WriteLine(Int.Parse(num)); //you'll need special handling to print "<no value>" when the string is 0000000
}
```

(haven't actually compiled this)